# Merge (Left Join) 2 XML files based on an Element attribute using xslt 3.0

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-3.0

I am new to xslt and I was trying to merge 2 xml files - expecting something like Left join but its not working as expected. It would be great and much appreciated if you guys could help me on this.

The matching ID's in the second file should merge their data to the first file and ignore the rest of the non-matching Id's.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" exclude-result-prefixes="array fn map math xs">
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="doc1">
        <RECORDS>
            <RECORD>
                <PROP NAME="A">
                    <PVAL>text A</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="B">
                    <PVAL>text B</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="C">
                    <PVAL>10</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="Id">
                    <PVAL>1</PVAL>
                </PROP>
            </RECORD>
            <RECORD>
                <PROP NAME="D">
                    <PVAL>text D</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="E">
                    <PVAL>text E</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="F">
                    <PVAL>10</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="Id">
                    <PVAL>2</PVAL>
                </PROP>
            </RECORD>
            <RECORD>
                <PROP NAME="G">
                    <PVAL>text G</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="H">
                    <PVAL>text H</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="I">
                    <PVAL>10</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="Id">
                    <PVAL>3</PVAL>
                </PROP>
            </RECORD>
        </RECORDS>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="doc2">
        <RECORDS>
            <RECORD>
                <PROP NAME="J">
                    <PVAL>text J</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="K">
                    <PVAL>text K</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="L">
                    <PVAL>10</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="Id">
                    <PVAL>1</PVAL>
                </PROP>
            </RECORD>
            <RECORD>
                <PROP NAME="M">
                    <PVAL>text M</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="N">
                    <PVAL>text N</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="O">
                    <PVAL>10</PVAL>
                </PROP>
                <PROP NAME="Id">
                    <PVAL>4</PVAL>
                </PROP>
            </RECORD>
        </RECORDS>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
            <xsl:merge>
                <xsl:merge-source select="$doc1/RECORDS/RECORD">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="PROP/@Id"></xsl:merge-key>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-source select="$doc2/RECORDS/RECORD">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="PROP/@Id"></xsl:merge-key>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-action>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-merge-group()[1]/*, fn:current-merge-group()[2]/*"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:merge-action>
            </xsl:merge>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RECORDS>
   <RECORD>
      <PROP NAME="Id">
         <PVAL>1</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="A">
         <PVAL>text A</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="B">
         <PVAL>text B</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="C">
         <PVAL>10</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="J">
         <PVAL>text J</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="K">
         <PVAL>text K</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="L">
         <PVAL>10</PVAL>
      </PROP>
   </RECORD>
   <RECORD>
      <PROP NAME="Id">
         <PVAL>2</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="D">
         <PVAL>text D</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="E">
         <PVAL>text E</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="F">
         <PVAL>10</PVAL>
      </PROP>
   </RECORD>
   <RECORD>
      <PROP NAME="Id">
         <PVAL>3</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="G">
         <PVAL>text G</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="H">
         <PVAL>text H</PVAL>
      </PROP>
      <PROP NAME="I">
         <PVAL>10</PVAL>
      </PROP>
   </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paths don't match the input structure and you haven't checked whether there is a match in the first merge source so the following change should work:

```
<xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:merge>
            <xsl:merge-source name="doc1" select="$doc1/RECORDS/RECORD">
                <xsl:merge-key select="PROP[@NAME = 'Id']/PVAL"></xsl:merge-key>
            </xsl:merge-source>
            <xsl:merge-source name="doc2" select="$doc2/RECORDS/RECORD">
                <xsl:merge-key select="PROP[@NAME = 'Id']/PVAL"></xsl:merge-key>
            </xsl:merge-source>
            <xsl:merge-action>
                <xsl:if test="current-merge-group('doc1')">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="*, current-merge-group('doc2')/*"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:merge-action>
        </xsl:merge>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkj

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton for helping on this. On a closer look, it seems the Id got duplicated in the result. Is there a way to get rid of it while copying the data from doc2 to doc 1

Comment: I added except to get rid of the duplicate. <xsl:apply-templates select="*, current-merge-group('doc2')/(* except PROP[@NAME = 'Id'])"/> Thanks again @Martin Honnen

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMom